# Finding Tangent line for a Graph with the Natural Log

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I'm really confused on how my professor did this problem. Any in depth explanation would be awesome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This method is called "logarithmic differentiation", which is useful when you have a function represented by $ \ y \ = \ f(x)^{g(x)} \ $ .  You take the logarithm of both sides to get $ \ \ln y \ = \ g(x) \cdot [\ln f(x)] \ $ and differentiate both sides implicitly to get $ \ \frac{1}{y} \cdot y' \ = \ \frac{d}{dx} [g(x) \cdot [\ln f(x)] \ ] \ $ .  After working out the derivative on the right-hand side, you then multiply through by $ \ y \ $ , which is the original function, to get $ \ y' \ = \ y \ \cdot \ \text{R.H.S.} \ \ \text{or} \ \ y' \ = \ f(x)^{g(x)} \ \cdot \ $ (R.H.S.) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=x^{\frac1{x}}$$

This can be a very difficult function to differentiate using our common differentiating methods. So what your professor did is take the easy way out: Get rid of the exponent.

How do we get rid of exponents? One word - *logarithms*. We'll use a base-$e$ logarithm (natural logarithm) because differentiating it is simple. So we just take the natural logarithm of each side:

$$\ln y=\ln x^{\frac1{x}}$$

Well, it's a property of logarithms that the exponents come to the front. Hence the exponent of $\frac1{x}$ will be moved to be the coefficient of the term:

$$\ln y=\frac1{x}\ln x$$

Awesome. Now it's easier to take the derivative. You'll need to do a little bit of *implicit differentiation*. Start with taking the derivative of the left side. Recall that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln u=\frac1{u}\frac{du}{dx}$$

So the derivative of $\ln y$ with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln y=\frac1{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y'}{y}$$

(Nicer to see: $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$)

Now for the right side, something similar. Except we have to use the *product rule*. The product rule is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}uv = u \frac{dv}{dx} + v \frac{du}{dx}$$

Awesome. We have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{x}\ln x = \frac1{x} \underbrace{\left( \frac{d}{dx}\ln x \right)}_{\frac1{x}}+\ln x \underbrace{\left( \frac{d}{dx} \frac1{x} \right)}_{-\frac1{x^2}}=\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2}\ln x$$

We can now combine both sides:

$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2}\ln x$$

I say, don't bother even reducing. Just plug in the point to get the slope ($y'$):

$$\frac{y'(1)}{(1)}=\frac1{(1)^2}-\frac1{(1)^2}\ln (1)$$

$$y'(1)=1$$

And that's our slope! Now just plug it in to the normal slope equation:

$$y=mx+b$$

$m=1$, and we are at the point $(1, 1)$ therefore $b$ is:

$$1=(1)(1)+b$$
$$b=0$$

We are therefore left with the general equation:

$$\therefore y=x$$

Here's what they look like

[image]

Cheers!
-Shahar

Comment: Most detailed answer I've ever received on any stackexchange question i've asked. Awesome.